# What is the difference between collapsible and accordion in bootstrap?

Tags: html, bootstrap-4

What is the difference between `collapsible` and `accordion` in bootstrap?

sample Code collapsible:

```
    <div class="panel-heading">
  <h4 class="panel-title">
    <a data-toggle="collapse" href="#collapse1">Collapsible panel</a>
  </h4>
</div>
<div id="collapse1" class="panel-collapse collapse">
  <div class="panel-body">Panel Body</div>
  <div class="panel-footer">Panel Footer</div>
</div>
```

sample code for accordion

```
      <h4 class="panel-title">
    <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapse1">
    Collapsible Group 1</a>
  </h4>
</div>
<div id="collapse1" class="panel-collapse collapse in">
  <div class="panel-body">Hello World</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

**Key Differences:**

- **Collapsible Panel**: Standalone collapsing component; multiple panels can be open simultaneously.
- **Accordion**: Collection of collapsing panels; only one panel is open at a time within the same group.

**Collapsible Panel:**
The collapsible panel is a standalone component that collapses and expands when triggered. In your provided code sample for a collapsible panel:

```
   <div class="panel-heading">
    <h4 class="panel-title">
      <a data-toggle="collapse" href="#collapse1">Collapsible panel</a>
    </h4>
   </div>
   <div id="collapse1" class="panel-collapse collapse">
    <div class="panel-body">Panel Body</div>
    <div class="panel-footer">Panel Footer</div>
   </div>
```

- Clicking the link "Collapsible panel" will collapse or expand the content wrapped within `#collapse1`.
- This setup allows for individual panels to collapse and expand independently of others.

**Accordion:**
Accordion, on the other hand, is a collection of collapsible panels where only one panel can be expanded at a time. In your provided code sample for an accordion:

```
<h4 class="panel-title">
 <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapse1">
Collapsible Group 1
 </a>
</h4>
</div>
 <div id="collapse1" class="panel-collapse collapse in">
 <div class="panel-body">Hello World</div>
</div>
```

- Here, `data-parent="#accordion"` defines that all the collapsible panels are part of the same group (with the ID "accordion").
- Clicking on any panel within the accordion group will collapse any other open panel and expand the clicked panel.
- Only one panel within the "accordion" group will be open at a time, giving the appearance of an accordion where panels fold and unfold sequentially.

Answer (score 0):

According to [Bootstrap 4 Collapse](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/collapse), " **Accordion** Toggle the visibility of content across your project with a few classes and our JavaScript plugins." [[1](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/collapse)]

**Accordion** are useful when you want to toggle between hiding and showing large amount of content. [[2](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_accordion.asp)]

In bootstrap context wise, accordion is basically a collapse button with a lot of smaller info in it. Bootstrap use `card` to make an accordion.

A snippet from Bootstrap 4

```
<div id="accordion" role="tablist">
  <div class="card">
    <div class="card-header" role="tab" id="headingOne">
      <h5 class="mb-0">
        <a data-toggle="collapse" href="#collapseOne" aria-expanded="true" aria-controls="collapseOne">
          Collapsible Group Item #1
        </a>
      </h5>
    </div>

    <div id="collapseOne" class="collapse show" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="headingOne" data-parent="#accordion">
      <div class="card-body">
        Anim pariatur cliche reprehenderit, enim eiusmod high life accusamus terry richardson ad squid. 3 wolf moon officia aute, non cupidatat skateboard dolor brunch. Food truck quinoa nesciunt laborum eiusmod. Brunch 3 wolf moon tempor, sunt aliqua put a bird on it squid single-origin coffee nulla assumenda shoreditch et. Nihil anim keffiyeh helvetica, craft beer labore wes anderson cred nesciunt sapiente ea proident. Ad vegan excepteur butcher vice lomo. Leggings occaecat craft beer farm-to-table, raw denim aesthetic synth nesciunt you probably haven't heard of them accusamus labore sustainable VHS.
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="card">
    <div class="card-header" role="tab" id="headingTwo">
      <h5 class="mb-0">
        <a class="collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" href="#collapseTwo" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseTwo">
          Collapsible Group Item #2
        </a>
      </h5>
    </div>
    <div id="collapseTwo" class="collapse" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="headingTwo" data-parent="#accordion">
      <div class="card-body">
        Anim pariatur cliche reprehenderit, enim eiusmod high life accusamus terry richardson ad squid. 3 wolf moon officia aute, non cupidatat skateboard dolor brunch. Food truck quinoa nesciunt laborum eiusmod. Brunch 3 wolf moon tempor, sunt aliqua put a bird on it squid single-origin coffee nulla assumenda shoreditch et. Nihil anim keffiyeh helvetica, craft beer labore wes anderson cred nesciunt sapiente ea proident. Ad vegan excepteur butcher vice lomo. Leggings occaecat craft beer farm-to-table, raw denim aesthetic synth nesciunt you probably haven't heard of them accusamus labore sustainable VHS.
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="card">
    <div class="card-header" role="tab" id="headingThree">
      <h5 class="mb-0">
        <a class="collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" href="#collapseThree" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseThree">
          Collapsible Group Item #3
        </a>
      </h5>
    </div>
    <div id="collapseThree" class="collapse" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="headingThree" data-parent="#accordion">
      <div class="card-body">
        Anim pariatur cliche reprehenderit, enim eiusmod high life accusamus terry richardson ad squid. 3 wolf moon officia aute, non cupidatat skateboard dolor brunch. Food truck quinoa nesciunt laborum eiusmod. Brunch 3 wolf moon tempor, sunt aliqua put a bird on it squid single-origin coffee nulla assumenda shoreditch et. Nihil anim keffiyeh helvetica, craft beer labore wes anderson cred nesciunt sapiente ea proident. Ad vegan excepteur butcher vice lomo. Leggings occaecat craft beer farm-to-table, raw denim aesthetic synth nesciunt you probably haven't heard of them accusamus labore sustainable VHS.
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

on line 1, `<div id="accordion" role="tablist">`, this is where the `data-parent` refers to.

on line 2 `<div class="card">`, we are using a card class, to show the card effect.

```
<div class="card-header" role="tab" id="headingOne">
      <h5 class="mb-0">
        <a data-toggle="collapse" href="#collapseOne" aria-expanded="true" aria-controls="collapseOne">
```

this 3 lines is just stating a new id `headingOne`, and then in the `a` tag, `data-toggle="collapse" aria-expanded="true"` is required for the effect of collapse, and the target is with id `collapseOne`.

Once you press that `a` tag,

```
<div id="collapseOne" class="collapse show" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="headingOne" data-parent="#accordion">
      <div class="card-body">
        Anim pariatur cliche reprehenderit, enim eiusmod high life accusamus terry richardson ad squid. 3 wolf moon officia aute, non cupidatat skateboard dolor brunch. Food truck quinoa nesciunt laborum eiusmod. Brunch 3 wolf moon tempor, sunt aliqua put a bird on it squid single-origin coffee nulla assumenda shoreditch et. Nihil anim keffiyeh helvetica, craft beer labore wes anderson cred nesciunt sapiente ea proident. Ad vegan excepteur butcher vice lomo. Leggings occaecat craft beer farm-to-table, raw denim aesthetic synth nesciunt you probably haven't heard of them accusamus labore sustainable VHS.
      </div>
    </div>
```

`<div id="collapseOne" class="collapse show" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="headingOne" data-parent="#accordion">`
 this line is self explainable, data-parent refer back to the id `#accordion`, `labelledby="headingOne"` and the role (tablist -the container of the tab, tab- the pressable button to toggle the panel, tabpanel- the content that are initially close, triggered by tab)

For more details, just read the official [Bootstrap collpase](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/collapse/)

#### Source:

1. https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/collapse
2. https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_accordion.asp

Comment: Downvoted: Not answered the question. The question is not definition of accordion; It's about the difference between accordion and collapse.